# Display image after dropdown right answer javascript

Tags: javascript

Im havin' this code. The target should be to display an image depending on the value of the select-tag code. ( More detailed ; To display the " Check" image if the answer is right and "x" if the answer is wrong. I have got a base code and modified & wrote on it quite much, but got stuck on this step as the images ain't displayin. Any idea ? :-?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/angelsmall13/cb4o9gsr/44/

```js
function finalScore(round) {

  var correct = 0;

  var selectValue;

  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //begin for loop

    //get the value of the select element
    selectValue = questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

    //if the value equals right
    if (selectValue === "corect") { //begin if then

      //increment the correct variable
      correct = correct + 1;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/4JKs8RV/check.jpg';
  
    } else if (selectValue === "gresit") { 

      correct = correct + 0;   
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg';      

    } else if (selectValue === "gresit")
{ 

      correct = correct + 0;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg';
    } 

  } //end for loop


  if (round === false) {
    //get the percentage of correct answers(not rounded)
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;
  } else {

    //display the rounded value
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;

  } //end if then else

} //end function
```

```html
<p>

What is the gender for Madchen?
<select class ="question" id="1howold">
    <option value="corect">Das</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
</select><br /><br />

What's the gender for " Mann"
<select class="question" id="2relationshipstatus">
    <option value="corect">Der</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><br /><br />
What is the gender for "Frau"?
<select class="question" id="3location">
    <option value="corect">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><br /><br />

<button type="button" onclick="finalScore(true)">Submit</button>

<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div> 
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 function finalScore(round) {

  var correct = 0;

  document.querySelectorAll('.ansimg').forEach(function(a) {
  a.remove()
})

  var selectValue;

  var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("question");

  var numOfQuestions = questions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) { //begin for loop

    //get the value of the select element
    selectValue = questions[i].options[questions[i].selectedIndex].value;

    //if the value equals right
    if (selectValue === "corect") { //begin if then

      //increment the correct variable
      correct = correct + 1;
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/4JKs8RV/check.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_"+i).appendChild(x);
  //var img = new Image();
  //img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/4JKs8RV/check.jpg';
  
    } else if (selectValue === "gresit") { 

      correct = correct + 0;  
      var x = document.createElement("IMG");
      x.setAttribute("src", "https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg");
      x.setAttribute("class", "ansimg");
      x.setAttribute("width", "22");
      x.setAttribute("height", "22");
      document.getElementById("img_"+i).appendChild(x);
  //var img = new Image();
  //img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg';      

    } else if (selectValue === "gresit")
{ 

      correct = correct + 0;
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = 'https://i.ibb.co/XWSYMSg/wrong.jpg';
    } 

  } //end for loop


  if (round === false) {
    //get the percentage of correct answers(not rounded)
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;
  } else {

    //display the rounded value
    document.getElementById("scoreDisplay").innerHTML = correct;

  } //end if then else

} //end function
```

```html
<p>

What is the gender for Madchen?
<select class ="question" id="1howold">
    <option value="corect">Das</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
</select><span id="img_0"></span><br /><br />

What's the gender for " Mann"
<select class="question" id="2relationshipstatus">
    <option value="corect">Der</option>
    <option value="gresit">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><span id="img_1"></span><br /><br />
What is the gender for "Frau"?
<select class="question" id="3location">
    <option value="corect">Die</option>
    <option value="gresit">Der</option>
    <option value="gresit">Das</option>
</select><span id="img_2"></span><br /><br />

<button type="button" onclick="finalScore(true)">Submit</button>

<div id="scoreDisplay">score goes here</div> 
</p>
```

I have modified your codes, please check the snippet

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Thank you <3

Comment: Might be an update, if you're willing to help with one more thing. I've created a reset button for the score, and even if if im quite sure i've wrote it well, it won't reset it. :(
Link : https://jsfiddle.net/angelsmall13/cb4o9gsr/104/

Comment: @TheStyle134 https://jsfiddle.net/trb24xh7/1/ check the fiddle I have modified your code. now its working fine. You have coded your arr() function inside of function finalScore()

Comment: Thanks so much buddy! Good luck and appreciate it <3

Comment: @TheStyle134 its okay, Its interesting to solve issues like this